# How to query attribute table in QGIS to return the sum of a subset

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, qgis

I am using Jupyter notebook to query a dataset too big to be opened with excel and my pc is too slow to perform calculations directly on QGIS.

My logic is as follows, after imported pandas:

```
x = df[(df.OBJECTID == 4440) & (df.Landuse == 'Grass - Urban')]
want_area = x['Area'].sum() #returning the whole dataframe sum for that field!!
summed = x['Area'].sum() 
ratio = round(want_area / summed, 2)
```

How can I tweak the code in order to obtain the sum of the '**Area**' of the above subset only, and not for the whole dataframe (800+ thousand features)?

Hope my simple question makes sense and thank you very much!

Comment: This -> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183037/calculating-sum-of-parts-of-column-based-on-another-column-using-qgis-field-calc/183060
sort of helps, but what is the logic in Jupyter Notebook to make an instant (and replicable) result?